# Возможно ли вообще создать дискорд бота для создания каналов и одновременного создания ролей, отправки во все каналы 1 сообщение

Tags: python, discord.py

Как сделать дискорд бота на **discord.py** чтобы он создавал канал с названием которое прописывается в коде, затем он создавал роль с названием которое прописывается в коде, и после этого ещё и отправлял сообщение во все имеющиеся каналы с текстом который прописывается в коде.
Сижу уже 3 день пытаюсь это сделать и думаю это вообще возможно??
вот что у меня получилось, помогите пожалуйста

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

from config import settings
intents=discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'],intents=intents)




@bot.event
async def on_ready():
            print("Bot is ready")
           
@bot.command()
async def c(ctx):
  guild = ctx.message.guild
  await guild.create_text_channel('F16')
  
async def send_all(message, member):
  channels = bot.get_all_channels()
  await bot.send_message(channels, message)  
  print('geting')
  bot.loop.create_task(c(ctx))
bot.loop.create_task(send_all())  
#@bot.event
#async def on_message(ctx):
   #await ctx.reply(ctx.content)
   #print('sended')
       





bot.run(settings['token']) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Sorry by advance, I'm not speaking nor understanding russian, but you posted your message in the english version of stackoverflow and your issue seems quite easy to resolve so I wanted to intervene.

Привет. Извините заранее, я не говорю и не понимаю по-русски, но вы разместили свое сообщение в английской версии stackoverflow, и вашу проблему кажется довольно легко решить, поэтому я хотел вмешаться.

You need to give your commands a name, so instead of "opening" a section for `bot.command()` you instead needs to declare a name for each command, that will execute with `prefix` + `command name`.

Вам нужно дать своим командам имя, поэтому вместо того, чтобы «открывать» раздел для `bot.command()`, вам нужно объявить имя для каждой команды, которая будет выполняться с `prefix` + `command name`.

```
@bot.command(name="c")
async def c(ctx):
  guild = ctx.message.guild
  await guild.create_text_channel('F16')

@bot.command(name="send_all")
async def send_all(message, member):
  channels = bot.get_all_channels()
  await bot.send_message(channels, message)  
  print('geting')
  bot.loop.create_task(c(ctx))

bot.loop.create_task(send_all())
```

I don't say your code will work, but at least you'll be able to test commands and get results, maybe to share here for further help. Also, but I am not sure since I never used it yet, I believe you have to pass something like `member : Discord.member` so it's not misinterpreted. Finally, I would, instead, suggest to get `context` (or `ctx`) instead of `member`, as most bot devs will use context as main argument in their commands (for examples it's easier to find with context or ctx).

I also never used the loop, but I fear it wont work since you pass "ctx" that isn't defined in your send_all (what you require as `member` and that could be called `ctx`).

Я не утверждаю, что ваш код будет работать, но, по крайней мере, вы сможете протестировать команды и получить результаты, возможно, поделиться здесь для получения дополнительной помощи. Кроме того, но я не уверен, так как я еще никогда не использовал его, я считаю, что вы должны передать что-то вроде `member : Discord.member`, чтобы это не было неправильно истолковано. Наконец, я бы вместо этого предложил получить `context` (или `ctx`) вместо `member`, так как большинство разработчиков ботов будут использовать контекст в качестве основного аргумента в своих командах (например, его легче найти с контекстом или ctx).

Я также никогда не использовал цикл, но боюсь, что он не сработает, так как вы передаете "ctx", который не определен в вашем send_all (то, что вам нужно как `member`, и это можно было бы назвать `ctx`).